# How to find public ip address without using third party website in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get a public IP address in Rails using request.env [] or gem or plugin or something else, but without using an external website, I have find my local ip address but can't able to find public ip address without using external website. I tried Socket gem also but that also not working for me. So please suggest for the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're connecting to your local server, you're local to Rails and have a local IP-address, and the reason lies in TCP/IP. If you need to know your external IP-address, you can make a call to APIs that provide your IP-address in any simple format, for example https://api.ipify.org?format=json:

```
{"ip":"123.123.123.123"}
```

Or just get page contents (https://api.ipify.org).

If you need this only in development environment, you could use it only for `Rails.env.development?`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I can know that we can get the public IP address using  https://api.ipify.org?format=json or  https://api.ipify.org and different external websites. But my concern without using these external link's, is there any possible to get the public ip address in rails. Please suggest.

Comment: @DiwakarAsok: "without using these external links" - nope, your app may be behind 5 layers of proxies and you can't possibly know the actual outer ip without travelling that network path (the simplest way of which is to make outbound request to a 3rd party).

Comment: Thank you. But could you please explain me in detail, why we can't able to get the public IP address without using these external links?

Comment: @DiwakarAsok look, when you connect to a local server, you just establish an internal local connection inside your system, skipping any other network, and introduce yourself with a local IP-address, and the server will never know about any external networks: they're just not used.

Comment: @DiwakarAsok and when you connect to external resources, you go through several layers of network, and on each layer you have a different IP-address, i.e., for your local router you're, let's say, 192.168.0.2, inside this router's network. Then router sends request to provider, and you have for example provider's internal address. And only here provider sends a request with your external address, and no one knows it before this layer. Tried to explain it in a simple way :)